# Samsung S5 compatible with tracfone and Verizon Wireless

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, sim-unlocking, verizon

I currently have Verizon wireless. I want to switch to tracfone and change my cell phone at the same time. I'm thinking about getting a Samsung S5. My question is, can I get a Samsung S5 to use with tracfone that will also be compatible with Verizon if I choose to go back? If so, what details should I look online when I'm shopping for a phone?
I think I need an unlocked phone but some say that it won't work with Verizon. I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having gone through this process, it seems that all Verizon-compatible Samsung S5s are compatible with TracFone, and there is no unlocking that needs to be done. All I had to do was get the new SIM card from TracFone and put it in the S5, then follow there instructions to get it activated. AFAIK, I could go back to Verizon at any time, by simply putting the old Verizon SIM card back in.

For any other model phone, just contact TracFone. They'll tell you whether the phone is compatible or not. It really was a straightforward process.